# tempfile module using fixed name

Tags: ansible

Can I create temp file with a fixed name with the `tempfile` module?

```yaml
- name: Create temporary file
  tempfile:
     state: file
     suffix: 2023-2-2
     prefix: app_010
  register: tempfile_1
  delegate_to: localhost

- name: debug
  debug:
      msg: "{{ tempfile_1.path }}"
```

The result is

```json
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "/tmp/app_010zvhvpiqr2023-2-2"
}
```

`tempfile` creates a random file name, but, I would like to give it a hardcoded name.
I want to read the temporary file from another playbook, so, should I use regex to find a file that starts with `app_010` and finishes with `2023-2-2`?

Answer (score 2):

The entire point of `tempfile` is to create unpredictable temporary files with a random component, because using a predictable name in a world-writable directory like `/tmp` has security implications.

If you want a predictable, hardcoded name, just use the `file` module.